# Android - Get results from subquery in cursor of android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I have a `subquery sqlite` :

```
SELECT BookDB.ArticleID,BookDB.Title, subquery.Title FROM BookDB, (SELECT 
MetaDataID,Title  FROM MetaDataDB  order by OrderView) subquery WHERE 
subquery.MetaDataID = BookDB.ArticleID;
```

This `query` get me results (in editor `sqlite`) but I can't see any result in `cursor` of android.

```
cursor = sql.rawQuery("SELECT BookDB.ArticleID,BookDB.Title, subquery.Title FROM BookDB, (SELECT 
MetaDataID,Title  FROM MetaDataDB  order by OrderView) subquery WHERE 
subquery.MetaDataID = BookDB.ArticleID;", null);
                    if (cursor != null) {
                        do {
                            cursor.moveToFirst();
                            String C = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("BookDB.Title"));
                            Log.i("results",C);
                        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                    }
```

Note: How I can get results from this line ?

```
String C = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("BookDB.Title"));
```

Comment: dump your `Cursor` with `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor` method

Comment: @pskink . How I can work with `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor` ? get me a link for sample please .

Comment: sample?  whats unclear in calling a method with one parameter?

Comment: I see this link and I use from `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor` but don't work.

Comment: what doesn't work? `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor` ?

Comment: Don't show any results . Thanks a lot .

Comment: what do you see on the logcat?

Comment: After this line `cursor = sql.rawQuery("SELECT...` I wrote `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursorid);` but don't get my any results in `logCat`.

Comment: no `">>>>> Dumping cursor "` at all?

Comment: None of them is worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change my `Query` and it worked :

```
cursor = sql.rawQuery("SELECT BookDB.ArticleID as ID,BookDB.Title as TITLE, subquery.Title as COMM FROM BookDB, (SELECT 
MetaDataID,Title  FROM MetaDataDB  order by OrderView) subquery WHERE 
subquery.MetaDataID = BookDB.ArticleID;", null);
                    if (cursor != null) {
                        do {
                            cursor.moveToFirst();
                            String C = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("TITLE"));
                            Log.i("results",C);
                        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                    }
```

Get me results now.